# RFduino and HC-05

Tags: hc-05

I am developing a project with RFduino, where I need to connect HC-05 Bluetooth module to my RFduino.

I have tried to find a way to do that, with out luck.

My question: Is it possible to connect HC-05 board to RFduino?

Note: this is my first question at Arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Connect it to the UART pins and send the right AT commands? What part of it are you struggling with?

Comment: in RFduino there is no UART pins, therefore I was wondering if some one has knowledge about RFduino (http://www.rfduino.com/product/rfd22102-rfduino-dip/index.html)

Comment: What about pins 0 and 1 - aren't they the uart?

Comment: I will try and let you know later, thx for informative feedback so far (pin 0 and 1 are called GPIO 0/AREF and GPIO1

Comment: The lack of documentation with those boards is kind of frustrating.  Your best bet is to delve into the actual source code, where you can see in the variant.h file for the board that the "default UART pins" are 0 and 1.  https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino/blob/master/variants/RFduino/variant.h#L133

Comment: cool I will work on it right a head. and will come back with feedback

Comment: It is btw frusrating. :)